# Disable or Rename Install4J Generated Files

Tags: install4j

Using Install4J 8 with the Install4J Gradle plugin 10.0.5, is it possible to disable or rename the updates.xml and output.txt files output during installer compilation?  For various reasons, we output multiple installer executables from multiple Gradle modules to a single directory. Subsequent calls to the Install4J compiler cause earlier versions of these files to be overwritten.  It also disables Gradle up-to-date checking.

I've tried using the quiet flag but output.txt is still created.

Answer (score 0):

As of install4j 10.x, this is not possible. You would have to rename the files after the build finishes, assuming that the builds do not run concurrently.